# I start docker container with IBM MQ, but i can't connect to it

Tags: docker, ibm-mq, amd-processor

I start docker container with IBM MQ, but i can't connect to it. Containers log always identical:

```
[+] Running 1/0
 - Container ibm-ibm-mq-1  Created                                                                                 0.0s
Attaching to ibm-ibm-mq-1
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.061Z CPU architecture: amd64
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.061Z Linux kernel version: 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.061Z Container runtime: docker
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.061Z Base image: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.061Z Running as user ID 1001 with primary group 0
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.061Z Capabilities (bounding set): chown,dac_override,fowner,fsetid,kill,setgid,setuid,setpcap,net_bind_service,net_raw,sys_chroot,mknod,audit_write,setfcap
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.061Z seccomp enforcing mode: filtering
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.061Z Process security attributes: none
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.061Z Detected 'ext4' volume mounted to /mnt/mqm
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.118Z Using queue manager name: QM1
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.122Z Created directory structure under /var/mqm
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.122Z Image created: 2020-05-27T11:03:04+00:00
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.122Z Image tag: ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev:9.1.5.0-r2-amd64
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.129Z MQ version: 9.1.5.0
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.129Z MQ level: p915-ifix-L200325.DE
ibm-ibm-mq-1  | 2022-07-27T13:28:33.129Z MQ license: Developer
```

Last string always: MQ license: Developer

My docker-compose.yml file below. I tried another version of IBM MQ and result was the same.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  ibm-mq:
    image: ibmcom/mq:9.1.5.0-r2
    networks:
      - mq-demo-network
    volumes:
      - "qm1data:/mnt/mqm"
    ports:
      - "1414:1414"
      - "9443:9443"
    environment:
      - LICENSE=accept
      - MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1

volumes:
  qm1data:

networks:
  mq-demo-network:
```

I work on Windows 10. Yesterday I have started IBM MQ container on this machine once and all was fine, but today something wrong. I tried to do it on another machine (Windows 10, identical Docker version) and all fine on it too.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `networks` and `volumes` specifications? Both in the root, and in the service spec.

Comment: @Pete same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is IBM MQ bug on some new AMD CPUs.
Fortunately, there is workaround. Set ICC_SHIFT=3 in the container environment.

https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/issues/462

Comment: Did this fix the start up issue? Seems to me that your issue of starting once, then not being able to was more related to resources (eg. ports) not being released.

Comment: @chughts Yes, this fix the issue. The issue definitely was not related to resources. First successful starting is just a coincidence. My laptop was powered by a battery at moment of the first start up. This strange bug will not reproduce, if laptop is powered by a battery.